# Who are these characters at the end of Deathly Hallows, Part 2?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, character-identification

In the process of answering [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84018/who-was-the-third-kid-with-harrys-and-ginnys-kids) question, I came across the following screenshot of several children on the Hogwarts Express, during the "Epilogue" scene of *Deathly Hallows, Part 2*:

[image: Assorted second-generation munchkins]

With the caveat that I haven't actually *seen* the movie, I can identify three of these five characters based on <s>intensive research</s> trawling [the infamous wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page):

The two boys on the right are clearly [James](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/James_Potter_II) and [Albus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Albus_Potter) Potter, Harry and Ginny's two oldest kids:

[image: James Potter II]
[image: Albus Potter]

And the nearest girl on the left is clearly [Rose Weasley](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rose_Weasley), Hermione and Ron's oldest:

[image: Rose Weasley]

Obviously this scene is (mostly) a movie invention; the relevant passage from the book only says:

> Albus jumped into the carriage and Ginny closed the door behind him. Students were hanging from the windows nearest them. A great number of faces, both on the train and off, seemed to be turned toward Harry.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Albus, Rose, Hugo, and Lily laughed. The train began to more, and Harry walked alongside it, watching his son's thin face, already ablaze with excitement. Harry kept smiling and waving, even though it was like a little bereavement, watching his son glide away from him...
>
> <sup><sub>*Deathly Hallows* Epilogue: "Seventeen Years Later"</sub></sup>

So my question is, **who are the other two girls?**

It occurs to me that one of them (maybe the black-haired one in the back?) is possibly Bill and Fleur's daughter [Victoire](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Victoire_Weasley), but [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) doesn't credit her, or any other named characters, and I can't think of any other identified second-generation children who would make sense here.

**Is there any official identity given to these characters, or are there other children I've forgotten who could be appearing uncredited?**

I'd prefer a statement from either Rowling or the film's writer/director/producers, but anything that identifies these characters (or the actresses, for that matter) is acceptable. Unless it's fanfiction.

Comment: They Look a lot older, like 4th or 5th years, I thought about this and just thought they're probably just unknown older students. That train can be pretty full on September 1st

Comment: @ZenLogic Or friends of James', since (according to the wikia) James is potentially as old as 15. I suspect that's going to be the right answer, but it doesn't hurt to ask

Comment: James is in his second year, so he is around 12 I think

Comment: @ZenLogic Has that been confirmed? I mean we know he's *at least* that old, but nothing I've found has come down firmly on a particular number

Comment: I don't have the books with me right now, as I'm in college, but I always thought the books said he was in his second year (possibly Harry/Gibby mentioning James was just as scared as Albus was *last year* or something), perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: @ZenLogic I *think* you're mistaken, but I seem to have lost my copy of DH so I can't verify

Comment: I'll check it when I'm home in a fee hours and confirm

Comment: @ZenLogic I found a [bootleg ebook](http://www.ebooksfreeonline.net/Fiction/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows/37.html), and it doesn't come down definitively. James knows about Thestrals, which is a possible indication that he's going into at least third year, but it's far from conclusive

Answer (score 3):

I believe they are just some other students.

I can´t remember anything referencing to them in the books, so their only purpose was to smile and wave in this Scene.

Comment: Competition winners?

Comment: Yes maybe. But I believe they are just background actors.